# How to validate value entered into a textbox and prevent switching to another control?

Tags: c#, uwp, focus

I'm working on a uwp desktop application that must validate values entered in textboxes so that they are of type double. If they are not, the focus must remain on the current control. I tried the code below.

```
private async void tbxValue_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(tbxValue.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
        
            MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(resourceLoader.GetString("MsgDlgValueError"));
            await msgDlg.ShowAsync();

        }
    }
```

EDIT

I found a solution thanks to Flydog57's comments.

```
private async void myTextBox_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
    {
        if(!double.TryParse(((TextBox)sender).Text, out double dbl))
        {
            bool bolCancel = args.TryCancel();

            if(bolCancel)
            {
                MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(resourceLoader.GetString("MsgDlgValueError"));
                await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Convert.ToDouble` in a try/catch, use `double.TryParse`. It will tell you if the string is a valid double, converting it if it is

Comment: Have you looked at the properties of `LosingFocusEventArgs`, particularly the `Cancel` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [@Flydog57's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844401/how-to-validate-value-entered-into-a-textbox-and-prevent-switching-to-another-co/75907701?noredirect=1#comment133782657_75844401).

In this approach, I use the `LosingFocus` event to test whether the text typed in my `TextBox` corresponds to a double type number, using the `double.TryParse` method. If the value is not valid, I keep the focus on the `TextBox` and display a message to the user.

```
private async void myTextBox_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    if(!double.TryParse(((TextBox)sender).Text, out double dbl))
    {
        bool bolCancel = args.TryCancel();

        if(bolCancel)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(resourceLoader.GetString("MsgDlgValueError"));
            await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need to validate the input value, you could handle the [TextBox.TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanged?view=winrt-22621). Then check the double value.

But there is one thing that needs to be remember. If you want to popup the Value Error message using other controls like `MessageDialog` or `ContentDialog` or `PopUP`, the `TextBox` will definitely lose focus. This is by design. The popup content will gain focus.  For other scenaios, we could handle the [LostFocus Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.lostfocus?view=winrt-22621) and manually set focus status to prevent the `TextBox` lost its focus.

The code looks like the following:

```
 private async void MyBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       double dbl = 0;
       var isDouble= double.TryParse(MyBox.Text, out dbl);
        if (!isDouble) 
        {
            MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog("123123");
            await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    private void MyBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```